# btechco.excelexport is not a function

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.btechco.excelexport.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnExport").click(function () {
        $("#tblExport").btechco_excelexport({
            containerid: "tblExport"
           , datatype: $datatype.Table
        });
    });
});
</script>

<Table id="tblExport">
<tr><td><button id="btnExport" >Export</button></tr>
<tr><Td>Name</td></tr>
</table>
```

The same script is working perfect for one website and is not working in another.  the only difference between these is bootstrap and codeigniter.  Will this plugin does not work with bootstrap css.  Is there a way to resolve this conflict or anything else is the error?

Comment: You're also missing a jQuery plugin it seems.

Comment: Are you sure `jquery.btechco.excelexport.js` loads correctly (look in the "Network" tab)? Do you load it *after* jQuery?

Comment: all jquerys added. and yes..jquery_latest is added before btecho scripts and all scripts are loaded properly (checked in Network tab)..The page just seems to load again when export button is clicked